# Can I set a configSource for mailSettings in C:\ProgramData?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

**Background:**

I have an application that for distribution and dependency bundling reasons is installed using Inno Setup, but at its core it's an ASP MVC 5 web app.

I'd like users to be able to install in Program Files as it's a natural place to place programs, and the average user will expect to be able to do this.

**The Problem:**

Some configuration files are modifiable through the app to admin users. These configuration files take the form of language strings, mail settings, etc.

The problem arises if the application is installed to Program Files. The IIS hidden user account running the application doesn't have write access to this directory, so config files inside the application directory cannot be modified by the application.

The solution I thought of was to place modifiable files inside a folder in C:\ProgramData, which is modifiable by the application. Here is where I hit an error. After changing mail settings to look like this in mt `web.config`

```
<smtp configSource="C:\ProgramData\myapp\Config\mailSettings.config" />
```

I get this error.

[image: runtime error]

**Question:**

Can I not link configSource to directory outside of the application? If not, is there a way around this?

Cheers.